# Calculating the angular power spectrum of a section of sky

Tags: cosmology, temperature, spherical-harmonics

To calculate the [angular power spectrum](http://background.uchicago.edu/~whu/intermediate/map5.html) $C_l$ of the whole sky, one uses the variance of the coefficients of the [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) in the temperature fluctuation field. I.e.

$$C_l = \frac{1}{2l+1}\sum^{l}_{m=-l} (a_{lm}^{*} a_{lm})$$

How does one calculate the $C_l$ of a sub-set of the sky? Does one still decompose the temperature field in this sub-set into spherical harmonics and use the corresponding $a_{lm}$? This would seem inappropriate to me as the spherical harmonics are defined across the whole sky (surface of sphere) and would surely be a bad basis for a decomposition of the temperature field from a small section of the sky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed spherical harmonics are inappropriate, since they are not orthogonal on the restricted domain. This is particularly noticeable in small-scale surveys like ACT and BOOMERanG, but even "full-sky" surveys mask bad data. COBE for instance masked out the entire galactic plane, so the problem has been known since then.

---

The solution presented by Górsky ([1994 ApJ, 430, L85](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994ApJ...430L..85G)) is to Gram-Schmidt orthogonalize the spherical harmonics according to the inner product on the restricted domain. The procedure is as follows:

1. Order the spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}$ into a column vector $y$, with $Y_{\ell m}$ being element $\ell^2 + \ell + 1 + m$ of $y$.
2. Apply weights to each $y_i$ based on pixelization effects, resulting in $\tilde{y}_i$.
3. Construct the matrix $W$ according to $W_{ij} = \langle \tilde{y}_i, \tilde{y}_j \rangle_\text{cut sky}$.
4. Choleski-decompose $W = L L^\mathrm{T}$.
5. Define a new vector of basis functions $\psi_i$, where $\psi = L^{-1} \tilde{y}$.

The resulting set is orthonormal: $\langle \psi_i, \psi_j \rangle_\text{cut sky} = \delta_{ij}$. The relation between the bases is such that if $f = \sum_i a_i y_i$ and $f\rvert_\text{cut sky} = \sum_i c_i \psi_i$, then $c_i = L_{ji} a_j$ and $a_i = L^{-1}_{ji} c_j$. As the author points out, the lower-triangular nature of $L$ prevents the bases from scrambling each other too much.

My understanding is that this method does not scale particularly well with the number of pixels $N$ in the image (methods like this tend to be $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ or $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$).

---

An alternative is to use the restricted domain naively and then undo the statistical average effect of non-orthogonality. This was done in Hivon et al. ([2002 ApJ, 567, 2](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002ApJ...567....2H)).

Your theory predicts the values $C_\ell = 1/(2\ell+1) \cdot \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \lvert a_{\ell m} \rvert ^2$ for some function $f = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell a_{\ell m} Y_{\ell m}$. You measure $f$ in some places, with varying certainty, and with noise and other instrumental effects, and you want to extract the best values for $C_\ell$ from your data.

The suggested procedure can be summarized as follows:

1. Define your weighting function $W$ on the sky (which can vanish in places).
2. Do the naive spherical harmonic decomposition of your data: $\tilde{a}_{\ell m} = \int_\text{sky} f W Y_{\ell m}^* \,\mathrm{d}\Omega$.
3. Bin over $m$ as usual: $\tilde{C}_\ell = 1/(2\ell+1) \cdot \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \lvert \tilde{a}_{\ell m} \rvert^2$.
4. Decompose the weighting function: $w_{\ell m} = \int_\text{sky} W Y_{\ell m}^* \,\mathrm{d}\Omega$.
5. Calculate the weighting function power spectrum $\mathcal{W}_\ell = 1/(2\ell+1) \cdot \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \lvert w_{\ell m} \rvert^2$.
6. Calculate the matrix elements
    $$ M_{\ell_1\ell_2} = \frac{2\ell_2+1}{4\pi} \sum_{\ell_3} (2\ell_3+1) \mathcal{W}_{\ell_3} \begin{pmatrix} \ell_1 & \ell_2 & \ell_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2 $$
    using the [Wigner 3-j symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_3-j_symbols).
7. The theoretical prediction relates to the observed values in a statistically averaged sense: $\langle \tilde{C}_\ell \rangle = \sum_{\ell'} M_{\ell\ell'} \langle C_{\ell'} \rangle$.

The paper goes on to discuss where beam width, filtering, and noise fit into the analysis, modifying how step (7) is used to extract the maximum likelihood estimators for $C_\ell$ given $\tilde{C}_\ell$.